# Local HTML files not opening properly

Tags: html, browser, jar, path, war

I'm having an issue with a local .HTML file.

Everytime I try opening it on ANY browser and on ANY computer it does not work, it opens normally for a brief second and then I get the screen saying the file path could not be found. If I spam refresh fast enough I can read the first lines.

The .HTML file has been extracted from a .war file.

If I copy the code into a new file and open that one, it opens up nicely.

The weird that got my attention was the path for the files themselves on the browser

The one directly extracted from the .war file is as follows:

```
file:///C:/Users/username/Desktop/New%20folder/help/User_Guide.html?1userhelp.html
```

but there is no file "User_guide.html" on the folder

If I create the same file just under the desktop directory it opens up without problems, so the issue is not the content of the file itself.

Does anyone have an Idea to what may be causing this problem?

Comment: You expect us to debug a problem with an HTML file we know absolutely nothing about, have no access to the contents of, and no ability to access  your machine to troubleshoot the issue?

Comment: I'm just looking if someone has experienced something similar. at least with that weird path the file is taking. Or what MAY be causing it. I can check and be here online for a long time if needed.

Comment: We aren't sure which OS you are using, and so case-sensitivity may play a part in this. If you're on Windows, you can try viewing the parent folder in the browser, and see if you can click on the file within the default index page and open it from there.

Comment: @Sunny: `C://Users` indicates it's definitely Windows.

Comment: There's nothing *weird* about that file path, other than that you've used `username` as a placeholder for the actual username.

Comment: Opening it from the index.html solved the problem! thanks, I din't thought at all about that one, I just wanted to open the file directly.

Comment: The placeholder is just to keep some info anonymous, since it uses ip as username.

Comment: i'll do some research on to why opening it from index works and opening it directly from the directory does not. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: Perhaps you had a typo in your original URI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by SunnyPatel

> We aren't sure which OS you are using, and so case-sensitivity may play a part in this. If you're on Windows, you can try viewing the parent folder in the browser, and see if you can click on the file within the default index page and open it from there

Opening the file by first going into "/index.html" worked just fine. The whole navigation flows perfectly, the issue was just me trying to open the file directly.